# Antonym for "evangelist" (in modern/technology industry usage)

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

The term "evangelist" gets used a lot by tech companies as a job title to describe those who try to push knowledge, use, and acceptance of a product, service, or company in a way which promotes the product/service/company. I was wondering what would be appropriate antonyms for this sort of usage. Given the very literal definition of relating to religion by most online dictionaries and thesauruses, antonyms are either not appropriate (such as layman) or non-existent. Given the pretentiousness of the term, I think an equally "weighty" term is most appropriate as an antonym.

Words that came to mind were: denouncer, antagonist, or decrier. I'd be interested in any thoughts on these terms as antonyms or any other suggestions.

Comment: How closely does this word need to resemble *evangelist*?  Would something more mundane, like *vocal/active/outspoken opponent*, work?

Comment: _Dysangelic_ might work, for the adjective form. _Evangelist_ comes from the Greek for 'good news', so if you swap the eu- prefix for a dys-, you get a literal opposite. Of course it's an adjective instead of an agent noun like _evangelist_; but if you're denouncing things or people, most people would connect the 'angelic' part with angels, and the _dys-_ is pretty clear, so that may be good agitprop.

Comment: @Juhasz I don't think it would need to resemble evangelist but a single term would definitely be preferred.

Comment: @JohnLawler I like the idea of going back to the Greek roots of the term. I'm not sure if "dysangelist" might be a bit awkward as far as using it as a noun, though. I'm going to have to repeat that one in my head a couple hundred times.

Comment: Try and include sample sentence for use-case.

Comment: I would use *deprecator*, as someone who actively disapproves and works to undermine something, esp., an idea or product. "‘In academic circles, the cognitive argument that students of design can learn both deeply and widely by using their hands with their minds has equally passionate advocates and **deprecators**.’" (https://www.lexico.com/definition/deprecator)

Comment: The reason why _dysangelic_ works while _dysangelist_ doesn't, phonetically, is because the noun stresses AN instead of GEL. That's the wrong stress pattern to match _anGELic_, but  the _-ic(al)_ suffix  moves the stress a syllable to the end, while the _-ist_ suffix doesn't attract the stress.

Comment: Somebody who speaks *against* something can be just as much an evangelist as somebody who speaks *against* something. So, to say that the opposite of an *evangelist* is any of the words you propose doesn't seem right to me. From my perspective, the opposite of an *evangelist* is a ***silencer***. But if you really want to equate evangelism with a pro stance as opposed to an anti stance, you should make that clearer in your question.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica This is true, although with the specific usage in the technology industry it always is in reference to someone who is pro something (since it's used as a Job title for someone working for the company). I can edit the question to make this clearer if you think it will help. I may have been assuming too much existing knowledge of the specific usage I was referring to.

Comment: @JohnLawler I was stressing the syllables for "dysangelist" the same way as I would "evangelist" and it seemed to sound fine to me. The AN is what seems to be stressed more in "evangelist" any time I've heard people use it and that is also how I'd see "dysangelist" being stressed. Definitely liking that term, especially since it's a new term constructed in the same manner as the original.

Comment: Are you **(1)** asking what is the **established** antonym for this word (used in this sense) or **(2)** seeking help in **inventing** the antonym? If (1), the answer is that there is no such word; if (2), the question is outside the scope of this site.

Comment: @jsw29 I was seeking an established word if one exists, which the three examples I gave as well as pretty much every other suggestion given applies. That said, I appreciate the creation of a new word that seeks to offer a better alternative than established words as well. If completely changing the meaning of an established word as has been done with "evangelist" is valid English (which it is), so is drawing from etymology to create a new word that best suits the situation. I'm not invalidating the other suggestions, but rather praising the thought and ingenuity in the newly created word.

Comment: ['doomsayer'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doomsayer) or '[nattering nabob of negativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabob#:~:text=The%20term%20was%20used%20by,%22nattering%20nabobs%20of%20negativism%22.)'

Answer (score 3):

**Naysayer** may work. From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/naysayer):

> : one who denies, refuses, opposes, or is skeptical or cynical about something
>
> (example) There are always naysayers who say it can't be done.

So if an evangelist promotes a *product*, a *service*, or an *organization*, a *naysayer* vocally opposes the product, position, or organization. For instance, a 2010 PC World article reported "[Windows Phone 7 Buzz Muted by **Naysayers**](https://www.pcworld.com/article/207220/Windows_Phone_7_Buzz_Muted_by_Naysayers.html)," with this body text:

> In fact Microsoft is facing a wall of **naysayers** leading up this Monday when it will introduce its first batch of Windows Phone 7 phones. Analysts and investors are wary about Windows Phone 7's prospects. Third-party application developers are giving mixed reviews about the new smartphone platform. And average Joes and Janes are just making wisecracks.

Answer (score 2):

Your word, *evangelist* is synonymous or at least 'homoionymous' with *missionary* and *champion*.  The words you have chosen could do.  The words you have chosen might do, though have an artificial and slightly heavy ring to them.

In the context that you mention, surely the polar opposite would be **'sceptic'** or **'critic'**.  The evangelist is literally a messenger (Greek αγγελος - angelos) spreading good (eu) news.  The opposite is one who casts doubt on the news in question.

There is another (biblical) word, generally used critically, that applies to someone given to saying that things will turn out badly.  Such people are often called **'Jeremiahs'**, after the prophet of doom in the Book of Jeremiah.  But I would suggest 'critic' or 'sceptic.